# Custom Command in WPF to allow dependency property value change in "realtime"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, commandbinding

I have a scenario where in my custom control I have a custom Dependency Property called `MinValue` of type `int`.

I want to allow the user to change that value via keyboard input Ctrl++ (increase) and Ctrl+- (decrease). I undertand this can be done with Commands, but am clueless as to where to implement those Commands. 
The user should be able to use the beforementioned keyboard shortcuts **no matter what control in the Window has focus.**

I think I would have to implement the Command in my custom control because only that control knows what to do with the keyboard shortcut, but since I have a listbox full of custom controls, and each should handle the shortcut, I'm not sure how that would work.
Any pointers?
Thanks as always!

Comment: When the command is executed, do you want EVERY instance of your control in the listbox to respond, or just the one selected?

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do this and probably good reasons to not do it this way, but here's an implementation that puts the commands on the user control:

User control code (could just as easily be a lookless control):

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        //Declare routed commands
        public static RoutedCommand IncrementCommand;
        public static RoutedCommand DecrementCommand;

        static TestControl()
        {
            //Create routed commands and add key gestures.
            IncrementCommand = new RoutedCommand();
            DecrementCommand = new RoutedCommand();
            IncrementCommand.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.Add, ModifierKeys.Control));
            DecrementCommand.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.Subtract, ModifierKeys.Control));
        }

        public TestControl()
        {
            //Subscribe to Increment/Decrement events.
            TestControl.Decremented += down;
            TestControl.Incremented += up;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Declare *static* Increment/Decrement events.
        public static event EventHandler Incremented;
        public static event EventHandler Decremented;

        //Raises Increment event
        public static void IncrementMin(object o, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (Incremented != null)
            {
                Incremented(o, args);
            }
        }

        //Raises Decrement event
        public static void DecrementMin(object o, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (Decremented != null)
            {
                Decremented(o, args);
            }
        }

        //Handler for static increment
        private void down(object o, EventArgs args)
        {
            Min--;
        }

        //Handler for static decrement
        private void up(object o, EventArgs args)
        {
            Min++;
        }

        //Backing property
        public int Min
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MinProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Min", typeof(int),
            typeof(TestControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
    }
```

The windows on which this behavior is desired need to add a CommandBinding for these commands. 
Window code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Raise control's static events in response to routed commands
    this.CommandBindings.Add(
        new CommandBinding(TestControl.IncrementCommand, new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(TestControl.IncrementMin)));
    this.CommandBindings.Add(
        new CommandBinding(TestControl.DecrementCommand, new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(TestControl.DecrementMin)));            
}
```

Does that help?

(Oh, BTW - as written this code only responds to the +/- keys on my keypad, not the ones above the (P)([)(]) keys - I haven't worked with key gestures before. Surely it can't be very had to correct.)